# androidplot: multiple y axes on the same graph

Tags: android, graph, androidplot

I am trying to display two sets of data on the same graph using androidplot; however, the data sets have very different scales.  Whilst I could do some kind of normalisation of the data sets to make them compatible, I would rather plot them on multiple y axes - e.g.

http://www.cohort.com/2yaxes.gif

I can pretty much do this in achartengine, but I think that androidplot produces better looking graphs and provides a "better" (i.e. more android like) architecture.

Does anybody have any ideas:
a) if it can be done?
and, b) how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that by now the answer is a little late to be of use, but here it is in any case:

Androidplot does not provide any built-int support for displaying multiple log scales using different tick intervals simultaneously.  As you already noted, the most popular workaround is normalisation, which forces you to use a shared tick interval.  Having said that, one Androidplot user was able to find a workaround by overlaying data:

[image]

Here's a link to the discussion:

http://old.androidplot.com/forum/index.php/topic,116.0.html

Comment: More details and code here: https://androidplot.jira.com/browse/ANDROIDPLOT-122 . Same solution by the same guy (ifor: http://stackoverflow.com/users/879508/ifor)

Comment: FWIW here's the full source of an example implementation: https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/6df44799ce4d63336f59ec82b3916ecf0b7fc9ba/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/DualScaleXYPlotExampleActivity.java?at=master